# If I have multiple datagridviews on one form, how would I allow a row selection to be active on only one at a time?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have two datagridviews which display two seperate stored procedures at the same time, both on the same form.  I have their "SelectionMode" properties set to "FullRowSelect".

However, I want only one row to be selectable at a time between the two dgvs.  So if someone selects a row on dgv A, I want the selected row in dgv B to unhighlight or deactivate.  And if someone selects a row in dgv B, I'd like the highlighted row in dgv A to unselect or deactivate.  Is there a way to essentially share a

`private void datagridview1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`

between two separate datagridviews?
I'm not sure where to begin with this, so I have no code examples.  Any assistance with this is appreciated.  Thanks!!

Comment: WPF Form? You mean a WinForm's Form. Why `SelectionChanged`? Maybe *share* a `Leave` event handler. -- Tag your question specifying the correct GUI platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When selecting in `dataGridView1`, call `dataGridView2.ClearSelection()`

You mentioned a single event handler to handle both, which you can do. And you can write some code to find all other DataGridViews besides the one you clicked, and clear their selections.

```
private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var s = (DataGridView)sender;
    if (s.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        var otherDataGridViews = this.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>().Except(new[] { s });
        foreach (var dgv in otherDataGridViews)
        {
            dgv.ClearSelection();
        }
    }
}
```

That will work if the DataGridViews are inside the same container i.e. same form, not in different Panels etc.

You must specify the same handler in the designer or designer code i.e.

```
// 
// dataGridView1
// 
...
this.dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dataGridView_SelectionChanged);
// 
// dataGridView2
// 
...
this.dataGridView2.SelectionChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dataGridView_SelectionChanged);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This seems to work, except that there has to be one click between the row in the opposite dgv deselecting, and selecting the row in the new dgv. So I select a row in dgv A.  And if I want to select a row in dvg B, I have to click once in B, which then unselects the row in A.  Then I have to click again to select the row in dgv B.  I hope this wasn't too confusing.  Other than that it works.  Any clues as to why this may be happening?

Comment: @Lguystillfly I just added a check inside the handler to see if anything was selected. The handler is being fired twice - once for deselection and once for selection. It appears to solve the issue you mentioned.

Comment: It did fix it!  Thanks so much again.  Much appreciated.  What's better is it makes sense.  Definitely learned something, thanks!